# Connect AWS private ALB from private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc

I have a complex networking requirement because of my clients current architecture. 
Will simplify as follows.

lets say I have 3 AWS VPCs.

**VPC 1**

```
CIDR : 10.0.0.0/16
 * I have a private ALB here. (xxx.elb.amazonaws.com)
 * peering connection to the VPC 2
 * No internet gateway
```

**VPC 2**

```
CIDR : 192.168.0.0/16
 * peering connection to the VPC 1
 * No internet gateway
```

**VPC 3**

```
CIDR : 20.30.0.0/16
 * peering connection to the VPC 2
 * No internet gateway
```

And I CANNOT modify VPC 3 network at all (ROUTE TABLEs etc.).

What I want to do is allowing VPC3 to access private ALB of the VPC1.

VPC 3 will route any traffic to 192.168.0.0/16 to the VPC2.

Thats all I know about VPC3.

I can do any modification to VPC1 and VPC2 (creating route tables, creating NAT gateways etc.)

How to connect to xxx.elb.amazonaws.com from VPC 3 which is only forwarding 192.168.x.x traffic to the VPC2.

In simple work VPC2 shoud forward some VPC2 address to the private ALB of the VPC1

ex: if an instance of VPC 3 accesses 192.168.something, it should point to the xxx.elb.amazonaws.com.

Comment: How does an application in VPC 3 "connect" to something? Is it trying to connect to a DNS name? An IP address? What do you mean by "if an instance of VPC 3 accesses 192.168.something, it should point to the xxx.elb.amazonaws.com"? Shouldn't it only connect if it actually wants to connect to a particular service/endpoint?